# How to make navigation drawer full screen and header image behind statusbar?

Tags: android, material-design, statusbar, drawerlayout

In my RecyclerView and DrawerLayout, I set `fitsSystemWindows="true"`. Also, I put `android:windowTranslucentStatus="true"` in my `v21/styles.xml`. I have tested everything, which was asked in old questions and answers, but none of them worked in my app.

[image: DrawerLayout]

I'm using Nexus 5, and tried everything to fix it.The image is starting under the statusbar. How can I put the image behind the status bar?

I dont know why it doesn't show parent layout, widget.DrawerLayout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="16dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewActivity_Main"
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I edited post. sorry for, publishing without code.